# change default value of textbox to new value and store new value after reopen

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a textbox(textbox1) which when the WPF Window is loaded, it used the UserProfile variable to show the current user directory in textbox1.text

```
   Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Dim defaultpath As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile")
    TextBox1.Text = defaultpath

    End Sub
```

I also have a button that when clicked, uses FolderBrowserDialog to browse for folder then shows the new folder path in textbox1.text.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fldDialog As New FolderBrowserDialog()
    fldDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
    fldDialog.ShowDialog()
    Dim filepathstore As String = fldDialog.SelectedPath

    TextBox1.Text = filepathstore
     End Sub
```

The value now shows the path that was selected with FolderBrowserDialog.

How would I store this new value and when WPF Window is closed/reopen, displays this new value instead of the default value. (replace not delete default value)

This new value of the folderpath can change as many times as needed. However when a reset button is clicked, the WPF window goes back to default value.

Comment: If you add the code where you create an instance of this form (e.g. show it) that may help people to answer you. Do you need to remember the value for as long as the programme is running? Or, do you need to save the value out to a file / database somewhere so it is remembered between sessions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the easiest option is to save the value to a file that can be recalled at any time. The below code assume the value you want to save is in textbox1.text when the FormClosing event is called, and then loads it back into textbox1.text when the form is opened.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim s As String
    s = TextBox1.Text
    Dim loc As String
    loc = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "/testfile.txt"
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(loc, TextBox1.Text, False)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim loc As String
    loc = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "/testfile.txt"
    Dim s As String
    s = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(loc)
    TextBox1.Text = s
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have a problem with this :)